# WebServices not working with Retrofit but working properly in Postman

Tags: android, web-services, retrofit2

I have webservices hosted on server but I am using Retrofit to fetch data from the server but When I am running my app it is showing exception `Unresolve host` but when I am using the same Url in Postman and browser it is working fine.I have also add Internet permission in app manifest file.

Below is my code:

**RetrofitClient.java**

```
public class RetrofitClient {

private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

public static Retrofit getInstance(){

    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(22, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(22, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(22, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();

    if(retrofit == null)
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://adbhutbharat.com/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(new GsonBuilder().setLenient().create()))
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .build();

    return retrofit;
  }

}
```

**ApiService.java**

```
public interface ApiService {

@GET("app/getAgents.php")
Call<List<Agents>> allAgents();

}
```

The above endpoint is working properly in postman and browser but not when requesting using retrofit  in android to fetch data.

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Can you post the stack trace of your error

Comment: yeah stack trace please.

Comment: It is showing something like this exception  `Socket failed : EPERM(operation not permitted)` even if I have added necessary permission in manifest file.